# How to use Faceapp.js in static website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, npm

Installed node_modules and added faceapp.js as a dependency. Trying to use faceapp.js but didn't work.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/faceapp/bin/faceapp.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h1 class="text-center">Faceapp</h1>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Javascript

```
const faceapp = require('faceapp');

let image = await faceapp.process('assets/images/ajith.jpg', 'smile_2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're trying to add an npm module to a static web. You'll need to bundle the script and required modules that you're using first and include the bundled script to your static html.
I recommend looking at [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) on how to do so.

Comment: Hi @RameshKR if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/faceapp/bin/faceapp.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="text-center">Faceapp</h1>

</body>

</html>[`enter image description here`][1]
```

Comment: You should add explanation.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).